# How to calculate the exact evolution of a one-body fermionic operator?

Tags: hilbert-space, operators, hamiltonian, quantum-computer, time-evolution

To simulate fermionic systems on a quantum computer, one has to do transformation from fermionic to bosonic operators. This transformation can be done for example with the Jordan-Wigner transformation.

I would like to understand how to compute the evolution $e^{-iHt}$ of the non-interaction Hamiltonian

\begin{equation} H = \sum_{pq} T_{pq} a^\dagger_p a_q  \end{equation}

so that one can implement the time evolution on a quantum computer.

Following https://quantumai.google/openfermion/tutorials/circuits_1_basis_change#openfermion_example_implementation_exact_evolution_under_tight_binding_models, the result of the time evolution should be
\begin{equation}
U^\dagger \left[ \prod_{k} e^{-i \lambda_k Z_k t} \right]U
\end{equation}
where $\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues of $H$. $Z_k$ is the Pauli $z$-matrix. $U$ is the unitary matrix that diagonalizes $H$.

My question is how to derive the time evolution under $H$ as given above.

After some comments, my approach is (please check carefully):

1. The time evolution of a state $\psi(t)$ can be written as $\psi(t) = U^\dagger U e^{-iHt} U^\dagger U \psi(0)$ since $U^\dagger U = 1$.
2. The term $U e^{-iHt} U^\dagger$ is diagonal since $U$ chosen such that it diagonalizes $H$. The diagonal Hamiltonian is $H=\sum_k \lambda_k b_k^\dagger b_k$.
3. Applying Jordan-Wigner transformation, the Hamiltonian is $H = \sum_k \lambda_k Z_k$.
4. The time evolution then becomes  $\psi(t) = U^\dagger \left[ e^{-i \sum_k \lambda_k Z_k t} \right] U \psi(0) = U^\dagger \left[ \prod_{k} e^{-i \lambda_k Z_k t} \right]U \psi(0)$.

Comment: there is no time in your expression for the time evolved operator?

Comment: There should be time in the exponent. It was an error and I corrected the equation for the time evolution.

Comment: Have you looked at how the [Jordan-Wigner transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Wigner_transformation) you mention works? It seems your question boils down to understanding the mapping from fermionic operators to Paulis, which is exactly what the transformation does.

Comment: Yes thats true! I edited the above question and added my approach how to derive the time evolution.

Comment: $\psi(0)$ evolves into $\psi(t)=U^\dagger \psi(0) U$, if $U$ is the time evolution operator for the many-fermion system. But there is a much easier way to write the time evolution of $\psi$: Since the Hamiltonian is quadratic, the equation of motion for $\psi$ is linear. So you can just solve it directly and it will be of the form $\psi(t)=V\psi(0)$ where $V$ is a $N\times N$ matrix, if there are $N$ fermion modes.